# How to store XMLs in Unity for web player deployment?

Tags: unity, web, xml

I've created with Unity a short demo that works as a standalone .exe on Windows, and I was interested in deploying it as a web player game too.

When I run the game on the web player, though, I get this error in the Unity console:

> **StreamingAssets is not available on this platform.**

I have some XMLs I parse at runtime in the *StreamingAssets* folder. Where can I put them in a web player build so to be able at runtime to load them?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution so to use the same code for both Windows and Web Player deployment (disclamer: I'm just reading these XML files): you can put the XMLs in the *Resources* located into the Project *Assets* folder. This basically tells to Unity to keep these files into the final build and you can load them at runtime using (in case of xmls for example):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
TextAsset myXmlAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("myXml");
doc.LoadXml(myXmlAsset.text);
```

I hope this helps someone :)